# Performance between looping twice separately and looping within a loop

Tags: performance, loops

Is there any performance difference between looping twice separately and looping within a loop?
How to prove it or calculate it?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you mean?

Comment: Speaking generally, the first is `O(n)` (linear time) and the second is `O(n^2)` (quadratic time).

Comment: Based on your description it seems like a difference between `O(2n)` and `O(n^2)` - please post some example code

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz agreed, as per my earlier comment (but remember, `O(2n)` **is** `O(n)`).

Comment: @MattBall: of course, I wrote `2n` just to emphasize we have two loops.

Comment: I was just trying to compare the very basic ones like 2 seperate loops for(i from 1 to n) {} (2 times) and for(i from 1 to n) { for(j from 1 to n) {} }. So based on the discussions here, linear's faster for a small n? or is it always faster than quadratic time?
Thank you all you guys for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the loops. Here are some examples of `O(n^2)` running time:

```
1) Nested loops to n

for(i from 1 to n){
    for(j from 1 to n){
        ...
    }
}

2) Nested loops to n with the inner loop starting from i

for(i from 1 to n){
    for(j from i to n){
        ...
    }
}

3) Second loop iterates n^2 times since i == n

for(i from 1 to n){
    ...
}
for(j from 1 to i*n){
    ...
}

4) One loop up to n*n/50

for(i from 1 to n*n/50){
    ...
}
```

Here are some examples of `O(n)` loops:

```
1) Simple loop

for(i from 1 to n){
    ...
}

2) Nested loop with constant iterations

for(i from 1 to n){
    for(j from 1 to 5){
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you have the fact that better time complexities aren't always faster for small enough `n`, like the loop to `n*n/50`. If `n` is less than `8` (a positive int) then that loop won't iterate at all, so it will obviously be faster than a the Simple loop with `O(n)`, which will iterate exactly `n` times.

Comment: Interesting! I was just thinking of the very basic ones. Seems like loops can get a lot more interesting!

Comment: @Jerry I saw your comment on the question, and the difference between your two simple loops the time complexity. The two loops side by side is `O(n)` and the two loops nested is `O(n^2)` what that means is that there is a certain `n` where from that point onward the side by side loops will always take less time. If we assume that the contents of the loops are identical (and ignore the loop header) we can get an exact answer for this situation:

Comment: The contents of the loop for the side by side ones execute exactly `2n` times and then contents of the nested loop execute exactly `n^2` times. So we can solve the equation `2n = n^2` for n. Divide both sides by `n` and you get `2 = n` (or `n = 2`).

Comment: So when `n` is `2` both loops take the same time (4 iterations). It's easy to see that when `n` is `1` the `n^1` one is faster (1 iteration). the side by side loops have 2 iterations. When `n` is 0 they are both 0 iterations. But when `n` is anything larger than `2` then 2 side by side loops will be less iterations. Say `n` is 10. Then you'll get `20` iterations with the side by side loops, but `100` with the nested loops. The larger `n` gets away from `2` the bigger the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking:

It could be `O(n + m)` if you've two distinct loops of different lengths (`n` and  `m`).

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {}
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {}
```

It could be `O(n * m)` if your looping within a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
   }
}
```